# auto_increment incremented on non-affecting queries

Tags: mysql, unique-constraint, auto-increment

When performing the following query on 'sessions':

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO sessions (user_id, archived) VALUES (3, 0)
```

while:

```
CREATE TABLE `sessions` (
  `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `date_created` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `date_modified` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `archived` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `valid_until` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `id_UNIQUE` (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `user_id_UNIQUE` (`user_id`),
  KEY `fk_sessions_users1_idx` (`user_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=18 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

with trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER before_insert_on_sessions BEFORE INSERT ON `sessions`
FOR EACH ROW SET new.valid_until = IFNULL(new.valid_until,DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY));
```

the first time you execute the query, everything is fine and the following is inserted:

```
id  user_id date_created    date_modified   archived    valid_until
1   3       ...             ...             0           ...
```

now enter the same query two more times, and it will say:

```
No errors, 0 rows affected, taking 8,0ms
```

Now change the query to:

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO sessions (user_id, archived) VALUES (4, 0)
```

So basically you only changed the value of user_id.

You'd expect the next row to be:

```
id  user_id date_created    date_modified   archived    valid_until
**2**   4       ...             ...             0           ...
```

instead, you get:

```
id  user_id date_created    date_modified   archived    valid_until
**4**   4       ...             ...             0           ...
```

So basically what's happening, is that the unique_key (id)'s auto_increment is being updated on every query, even though there are no actual new rows being made.

This shouldn't be right, should it?

```
Server version:     5.6.22 Homebrew
```

Comment: Why do you care if the auto incremented column is incremented?  What does it matter?  If you are relying on `id` not having gaps, you are probably thinking about it wrong.

Comment: You're right, I'll edit the post. Any suggestions on how to keep `id` clean and make it become 2 in stead of 4? @MaxVernon

Comment: Get rid of `id`, use `user_id` as the `PRIMARY KEY`.  And get rid of the redundant indexes.

Comment: @Rowan - create a key table and use it to manage the id values yourself.  Or simply stop caring if there are gaps that have absolutely no relevance.

Comment: The symptoms you are seeing occur because MySQL allocates the next available auto_increment value *prior* to attempting the insert.  If the `IGNORE` keyword is present, and the `INSERT` statement causes a duplicate key error, the engine will not roll-back the auto_increment action.

Answer (score 0):

> This shouldn't be right, should it?

It's right.

Databases (not just MySQL) generally ensure that sequences will only ever increase (once a transaction is committed), but not that they will be without gaps. For instance, [TFM](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/innodb-auto-increment-handling.html) says:

> You may see gaps in the sequence of values assigned to the AUTO_INCREMENT column if you roll back transactions that have generated numbers using the counter.

and:

> As of MySQL 5.1.22, InnoDB can avoid using the table-level AUTO-INC lock for a class of INSERT statements where the number of rows is known in advance, and still preserve deterministic execution and safety for statement-based replication. Further, if you are not using the binary log to replay SQL statements as part of recovery or replication, you can entirely eliminate use of the table-level AUTO-INC lock for even greater concurrency and performance, **at the cost of permitting gaps in auto-increment numbers assigned by a statement** and potentially having the numbers assigned by concurrently executing statements interleaved.

Consider the case where two uncommitted transactions exist in an [MVCC](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/innodb-auto-increment-handling.html) system like InnoDB. They may both need a unique primary key *before* being committed, but the first transaction may fail. Hence you will end up with a gap.

You can't avoid this behaviour, so embrace your gappy primary keys :)

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/innodb-auto-increment-handling.html

Comment: `REPLACE` _will_ burn ids.  `INSERT IGNORE`, `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`, `ROLLBACK`, and perhaps other statements _may_ burn ids.  Also, any multi-master setup (including Galera-based solutions) involves setting `auto_increment_increment` > 1.